How to Ensure All Methods in a Multiprocessing Job Show Up in OpenTelemetry Traces?
I'm working on a Python application that uses OpenTelemetry for tracing, specifically with a class that inherits from multiprocessing.Process. I have a Job class that executes a method (run_job) in a separate process, but I can only see the span for the start method in my tracing output.
I am using a custom instrument method, to implement manual instrumentation and produce traces on grafana
class Job(Process):
    def __init__(self, event_data: dict, module_name: str):
        super().__init__(target=self.run_job, daemon=True)
        # Initialization logic...

    @instrument
    def start(self) -> None:
        super().start()

    @instrument
    def run_job(self):
        # Logic for the job...
        pass

    @instrument
    def send_execution_result(self, commands, bot_variables):
        # Logic to send results...
        pass

    @instrument
    def submit_worker(self):
        # Logic to submit worker...
        pass

I am using opentelemetry version 1.23.0 and python version 3.10.0
The start method is inherited from multiprocessing.Process, and it is responsible for starting the process and running the target method (run_job in my case). However, I want all methods annotated with @instrument to appear in my tracing output. Currently, only the start method is being recorded.
How can I ensure that the run_job and other methods are also traced when executed in a separate process? Are there specific configurations or context propagation steps I need to take to achieve this?
Any help or examples would be greatly appreciated!
